# I have a British passport, don’t need a visa to travel to the US but have a earlier denial

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta, uk-citizens, denial-of-entry

In 1997, I was deported from the US; I was a juvenile. Long story short, 10 years later I was given a tourist visa, I never overstayed my time in the US, When I went to renew my visa, I was denied.

It’s been 8 years since I applied and I’m afraid I’ll be wasting my time going back to the Embassy only to be denied again. Since I have a British passport and can literally get on a flight to the US but will be stop by Immigration, should I go back to the Embassy again or just take a flight to see what will happen?

Comment: Why were you denied? What reason did they give you? You can't take a flight without an ESTA, and you don't qualify for an ESTA with a visa denial.

Comment: if you were denied a visa, you now are no longer excempt from needing a visa so yes, you have to apply for one.

Comment: The answers explain the ESTA requirement which makes the rest of this comment moot. However, in general, if you think you're likely to be denied a visa for whatever country, then you should also expect to be denied any kind of visa on arrival or visa waiver from that country. A formal visa application gives you _more_ chance of putting your case.

Answer (score 6):

Several years ago what you're saying would have been possible - with a UK passport you could have boarded a flight to the US, and then likely be refused entry once you arrive in the US (or not, depending on the circumstances).

Avoiding this type of situation is one of the reasons that the US instigated the "Electronic System for Travel Authorization", or "ESTA".  Under ESTA, anyone planning to arrive in the US by air and enter using the Visa Waiver Program will first need to obtain an "ESTA", or you will not be allowed board the flight.

Based on the limited information you've provided, it's likely an ESTA would be rejected - but you can certainly [try applying](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/).

And remember, lying on a visa (or ESTA) application will only make things worse, and could result in action up to and including a lifetime ban from entering the US.

Answer (score 1):

A visa denial makes you no longer excempt from the visa requirement, period.

An ESTA (which anyone who is excempt would need) would be automatically denied.

So yes, you need to go to the embassy or consulate and apply like everyone else who needs a visa to enter the USA.

If you try to board a flight to the USA from anywhere without a valid ESTA or visa, you're almost certain to be prevented from even checking in, let alone boarding. Not only do the airlines strictly enforce this as if they don't they face quite serious consequences from US authorities, but also US immigration officials are present in several countries interviewing people who want to board in order to weed out people who would not be allowed entry despite having an ESTA before the flight even takes off.

Comment: "A visa denial makes you no longer excempt from the visa requirement, period." According to what law?